# WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 - OAuth2 handler class - dependent jars org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub-4.2.2.jar

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a custom handler that will validate the token using OAuth2 and included the custom handler in REST API configuration. Copied the custom handler.jar to the /repository/components/libs directory which doesn't contain (org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub-4.2.2.jar). when I invoke the API with OAuth access token getting below class not found exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/stub/dto/OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO_OAuth2AccessToken
    at org.wso2.handler.SimpleOauthHandler.handleRequest(SimpleOauthHandler.java:61)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:285)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:336)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.stub.dto.OAuth2TokenValidationRequestDTO_OAuth2AccessToken
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

which is best way to include this dependent jar - org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub-4.2.2.jar?
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons for this...

1. AS `org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub-4.2.2.jar` is an OSGI bundle,  therefore you need to put this bundle in to the `/repository/components/dropins` . Normally jar files are put in to the `lib`  directory, not OSGI bundles
2. There can be some other jar file in your server `org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub` that expose same classes..  If please try to remove them..  As example, you can remove the OAuth mediator feature using `Feature Manager` management UI  (OAuth mediator feature already is packed with `org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub` jar file.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use IS 4.6.0 with the ESB 4.8.0 for oAuth authorization, you have to face this issue since ESB 4.8.0 uses the `org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub-4.2.1.jar`

If you want to implement the hanlder to use with IS 4.6.0, you can create the handler as an OSGi bundle including `org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub-4.2.2.jar` as a private package. But it seems not a good practice.
(Sample can be found at https://github.com/wenodpathirana/wso2-api-security-handlers.git)

In addition, If you use ESB 4.8.1 with IS 4.6.0, you can use the handler without the above exception as ESB 4.8.1 uses `org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub-4.2.2.jar`